# Why is SUMIFS not working across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, sumifs

I need to calculate how much has weight/volume of purchase contract has been fulfilled by suppliers. I have all the info in a large table, however it is not as simple as just using a SUMIF using the contract number as the connecting factor.

Each contract consists of multiple shipments. Each shipment has one of 11 status' (this includes a blank status). I need to sum the weight/volume of all the shipments of a certain contract, but I only add them to the sum if they are one of 9 of the 11 available status'.

I have used a SUMIFS function, noted below:

```
=SUMIFS($U$2:$U$350,$C$2:$C$350,$AO5,$A$2:$A$350,"<>"&"Pending Payment",$A$2:$A$350,"<>")
```

This function, when placed in the same sheet as the table with all the shipments, works perfect.

Issues arise when I move it to a different sheet, which is what I need to do. When I move this formula to a different sheet it changes to the below:

```
=SUMIFS('Expected Deliveries'!$U$2:U350,'Expected Deliveries'!$C$2:C350,$AO5,'Expected Deliveries'!$A$2:A350,"<>"&"Pending Payment",'Expected Deliveries'!$A$2:A350,"<>")
```

The difference is when I reference a section in the "Expected Deliveries" sheet the " 'Expected Deliveries'! " text is added before the column/row selection.

Comment: If you reference data on another sheet, you need the sheetname?

Comment: If you want the same formula to reference the new sheet in which you are placing it, copy the formula and not the cell.

Comment: I re-typed the formula from scratch, It is just the same formula but as I said only difference is that it references a sheet that isn't the one it's typed on.